# Javascript: Como activar una función después de hacer location.reload()

Tags: javascript, jquery

La idea es dar click en un botón que recargue la página y luego de que se haya recargado, activar un segundo botón que estaba deshabilitado:

**HTML**

```html
<a class="btn btn-outline-success mr-3 disabled" id="btn_categoria" href="#" onclick="categoria()">Consultar</a>
<a class="btn btn-outline-info" id="btn_limpiar_cate" href="#">Limpiar</a>
```

**JS**

```
$("#btn_limpiar_cate").click(function() {

  location.reload();
  $("#btn_categoria").removeClass("disabled");

});
```

Lo que está sucediendo es que se recarga la página pero NO se desbloquea el botón.

Comment: una ves se inicie el `reload` el siguiente codigo no se ejecutara, tambien la pagina se mostrara como en principio si quieres que se guarde las configuraciones te recomiendo [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Hummm, entonces después que se hace reload se rompe la continuidad de la función?

Comment: no solo eso javascript es un lenguaje del lado del cliente por ende simple que se haga una solicitud se pintara igual al menos que almacenes los cambios que deses

Comment: En este caso que no es un dato lo que necesito guardar sino una función ¿Cómo crees que lo podría hacer? No se me ocurre la forma...

Comment: para que requieres guardar una funcion? edita tu pregunta y agrega exactamente lo que deseas hacer para poder ayudarte mejor! si no ya te agrege una respuesta de como puedes hacerlo

Comment: Cuando dije función me refería a: $("#btn_categoria").removeClass("disabled");
Perdón si no fui claro :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes utilizar [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

ejemplo:

```
function validarbtn(){
 // validamos si existe en el localstorage la llave btn_categoria
 if(localStorage.getItem("btn_categoria") ==="1"){
  // si existe removemos la clase disabled
  $("#btn_categoria").removeClass("disabled");
 }else{
 // en caso de que no exista agregamos la clase disabled
  $("#btn_categoria").addClass("disabled");
// guardamos como desabilitado
localStorage.setItem("btn_categoria", 0);
 }
}

$("#btn_limpiar_cate").click(function() {
  // guardamos como habilitado el bottom btn_categoria
  localStorage.setItem("btn_categoria", 1);
  // refrescamos la pagina
  location.reload();
});
// llamamos a la funcion apenas inicializa el codigo
validarbtn();
```

Comment: Muy interesante. Voy a probar. Pero me queda una duda con la parte final: Como hago que validarbtn() se active cuando se inicia el código. ¿Acaso debo activarla con un $(document).ready o similar?

Comment: si debes agregarlo dentro del `$(document).ready` nota el `localStorage.getItem("btn_categoria")` retorna el valor en forma de string no de int ya hice la correccion saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu paciencia y colaboración. Ya pruebo con tu código y te comento como me fue.

Comment: Funcionó muy bien. Muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

A pesar de que encuentro super raro de que recargando el botón no se desbloquee, el único error de código que puedo ver es que la remoción de clase la haces después del reload y debe hacerse antes.

```
$("#btn_limpiar_cate").click(function() {
  $("#btn_categoria").removeClass("disabled");
  location.reload();
});
```

En el caso de que esto no resuelva tu duda, podrías colocar lo siguiente al inicio de tu página

```
function isPostBack() { //detecta el postback
  $("#btn_categoria").removeClass("disabled");
}
```

Comenta si funcionó, no dudes en preguntar si no.

Comment: Probé cambiando el orden de las sentencias dentro de la función y el resultado es exactamente el mismo.

Comment: Probé con la función isPostBack() pero no hace nada. Parece ser que solo funciona cuando se ha hecho un POST y no es el caso. Es solo uso de HTML con JS.